# How to list all the user's "member for" via "Views"?

Tags: views, 8, entities

In Drupal 8, there is a "member for" in the profile page to show that how long time since this user be a member until now.

I would like to list all the user's "member for" via Views. However there is no such variable in the Views FIELDS.

I was thinking create a user field called "member since" and then every day get the "member for" value (which in the profile already) everyday, and display this "member since" field via Views. However:

1. I don't know how to get the value of existed "member for" variable in Drupal 8 for created user field "member since". (of course I can calculate it by myself, but I don't want to deal the timestamp, formation etc)
2. I don't know how to run this function to get the value of existed "member for" variable one time everyday.

Or is there a better way to do it (Note I need to use Views to display it)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy to achieve. Simply add the user's `created` field to your view, then change the field formatter for this to `Time ago`.

[image: view field settings]

Comment: Thanks a lot! but there is an "ago" after the time. Like "2 years 2 months ago" what I want is like "member for" "2 years 2 months". Is there any way to remove the "ago" there?

Comment: @DHH probably the easiest is to do this is to override the `created` field twig template for your view / display - then just use the twig `replace` filter (https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) to replace ' ago' with an empty string.